# multi-level feature fusion in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to know how can I **combine** two layers with different spatial space in *Tensorflow*.

for example::

```
batch_size = 3

input1 = tf.ones([batch_size, 32, 32, 3], tf.float32)
input2 = tf.ones([batch_size, 16, 16, 3], tf.float32)

filt1 = tf.constant(0.1, shape = [3,3,3,64])
filt1_1 = tf.constant(0.1, shape = [1,1,64,64])

filt2 = tf.constant(0.1, shape = [3,3,3,128])
filt2_2 = tf.constant(0.1, shape = [1,1,128,128])

#first layer
conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(input1, filt1, [1,2,2,1], "SAME")
pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, [1,2,2,1],[1,2,2,1], "SAME")

conv1_1 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool1,  filt1_1, [1,2,2,1], "SAME")
deconv1 = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(conv1_1, filt1_1, pool1.get_shape().as_list(), [1,2,2,1], "SAME")

#seconda Layer
conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(input2, filt2, [1,2,2,1], "SAME")
pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, [1,2,2,1],[1,2,2,1], "SAME")

conv2_2 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool2,  filt2_2, [1,2,2,1], "SAME")
deconv2 = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(conv2_2, filt2_2, pool2.get_shape().as_list(), [1,2,2,1], "SAME")
```

The **deconv1 shape** is [3, 8, 8, 64] and the **deconv2 shape** is [3, 4, 4, 128]. Here I cannot use the **tf.concat** to combine the **deconv1** and **deconv2**. So how can I do this???

**Edit**

This is image for the architecture that I tried to implement:: it is releated to this paper::

> vii. He, W., Zhang, X. Y., Yin, F., & Liu, C. L. (2017). Deep Direct
>   Regression for Multi-Oriented Scene Text Detection. arXiv preprint
>   arXiv:1703.08289

[image: architecture]

Comment: The first answer comes in my mind, base on Tensorflow API, you can't do this concatenation operation. Since the concat can be done on an axis, (i.e. tf.concat([t3, t4], 1)  on axis one,) the other axis should have the same shape. Let me know why you want to do this concat, what is your purpose?

Comment: I try to do object detection. The approach used some of convolution layers followed with pool layers (each conv layer followed directly with pool layer). Then I used deconvolution layer (UpSample), each deconvolution layer take a different pool layers for example the deconv1 take the pool1 as input and so on.  My problem is in the next step: how can I combine (fuse) these deconvolution layers???

Comment: You can't do that, you can't concat two matrices with different shapes which results from different pooling layers. Edit your question and post the architecture you want to use, I will write the final answer to you and point that how to use the bottleneck pipeline architectures, like this one: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.03056.pdf

Comment: yes, I know that I cannot use the tf.concat, because that I asked this question. I want to know how can I solve this problem. I editing my question I hope that useful. and thank you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I checked the paper you point and there is it, consider the input image to this network has size `H x W` (height and width), I write the size of the output image on the side of each layer. Now look at the most bottom layer which I circle the input arrows to that layer, let's check it. This layer has two input, the first from the previous layer which has shape `H/2 x W/2` and the second from the first pooling layer which also has size `H/2 x W/2`. These two inputs are merged together (not concatenation, but added together based on paper) and goes into the last `Upsample` layer, which output image of size `H x W`.

The other `Upsample` layers also have the same inputs. As you can see all merging operations have the match shapes. Also, the filter number for all merging layers is 128 which has consistency with others.

You can also use `concat` instead of merging, but it results in a larger filter number, be careful about that. i.e. merging two matrices with shapes `H/2 x W/2 x 128` results in the same shape `H/2 x W/2 x 128`, but concat two matrices on the last axis, with shapes `H/2 x W/2 x 128` results in `H/2 x W/2 x 256`.

I tried to guide you as much as possible, hope that was useful.

Comment: Thank you so much Ali, it is a clear explanation and it is useful